# Message not added to store after SmsManager SendTextMessage

Tags: android, xamarin, smsmanager, maui

G'day,

My question is fairly straight forward:

Should I expect `SMSManager.Default.SendTextMessage()` to automatically add the sent message to the message store, or do I need to add it myself? If I need to add it myself, should I do that in the `BroadcastReceiver` or in the dependency service after sending?

For context:

I'm trying to recreate an SMS app as practice for myself.

I've managed to create a dependency service that gets messages from the message store and have a `BroadcastReceiver` to notify when a message is received.

My issue arises when I try to use the below code to send a message.

```
    public Task SendSMS(string message, string destination)
    {
        piSent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, destination.GetHashCode(), new Intent("SMS_SENT"), PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        //var piDelivered = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
        try
        {
            manager.SendTextMessage(destination, null, message, piSent, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.Make(e.Message, ToastDuration.Long).Show();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

So the `BroadcastReceiver` for SMS_SENT gets the intent and has a `Result.Ok` code, but the message itself isn't added to the message store. I also haven't live tested this to see if the message actually sends.

This is the code I use to get all messages from the store.

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Message>> GetMessages(string thread_id)
    {
        var inbox = App.Current.Resources["smsInbox"] as string;
        var cols = new string[] { "address", "_id", "thread_id", "body", "date" };
        var projection = "thread_id=?";
        string[] selection = { thread_id };

        var results = await ExecuteQuery(inbox, cols, projection, selection);

        var messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            messages.Add(new Message
            {
                Address = result[0],
                Id = result[1],
                ThreadId = result[2],
                Body = result[3],
                Date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse(result[4]))
            });
        }
        return messages;
    }

    private async Task<List<List<string>>> ExecuteQuery(string uriString, string[] cols, string projection, string[] projectionValue = null)
    {
        await init();
        var queryData = new List<List<string>>();
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uriString);
        var cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, cols, projection, projectionValue, null);
        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                var tuple = new List<string>(cursor.ColumnCount);
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    tuple.Add(cursor.GetString(i));
                }
                queryData.Add(tuple);
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
        cursor.Close();
        return queryData;
    }
```

And the broadcastreceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]
public class MessageSentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        switch ((int)ResultCode)
        {
            case (int)Result.Ok:
                Toast.Make("SMS Sent", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)SmsResultError.GenericFailure:
                Toast.Make("Generic Error", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)SmsResultError.NoService:
                Toast.Make("No Service", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)SmsResultError.NullPdu:
                Toast.Make("Null PDU", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)SmsResultError.RadioOff:
                Toast.Make("Radio Off", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.Make("Default Message", ToastDuration.Short).Show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this isn't enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after double-triple checking I wasn't making a fool of myself, turns out I was.

The messages are saved in the sent table, so weren't showing up when I pulled from the inbox.

Lesson learnt!

I guess I'll leave this here to save someone else that's having a brain fade.